# how to show divs in horizontal manner

Tags: html, laravel, bootstrap-4

hi I wants to show these columns in horizontal manner but these are showing in vertical manner ow can I change it;

blade file:

```
    <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
            <!-- Input & Button Groups -->
            @foreach($category->products as $pro_data)
            <div class="card card-small mb-4">
              <div class="card-header border-bottom">
                <h6 class="m-0">{{ $pro_data->product_name }}</h6>
              </div>
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item px-3">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">

                      <div class="input-group input-group-seamless">
                         <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/backend_images/category_images/{{ $pro_data->product_image }}" class="img-thumbnail" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;" />
                      </div>

                    </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            @endforeach
            <!-- / Input & Button Groups -->
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are trying to show the products of the categories next to each other horizontally but you are seeing them vertically at the moment.

I think a proper way would wrap the foreach with your 
`<div class="col-lg-3 mb-4"></div>` which gives us

```
<div class="row">
@foreach($category->products as $pro_data)
 <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
   <div class="card card-small mb-4">
     <div class="card-header border-bottom">
       <h6 class="m-0">{{ $pro_data->product_name }}</h6>
     </div>
     <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group input-group-seamless">
        <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/backend_images/category_images/{{ $pro_data->product_image }}" class="img-thumbnail" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;" />
       </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```html
@foreach($category->products as $pro_data)
<div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <!-- Input & Button Groups -->

          <div class="card card-small mb-4">
            <div class="card-header border-bottom">
              <h6 class="m-0">{{ $pro_data->product_name }}</h6>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
              <li class="list-group-item px-3">
                  <div class="input-group mb-3">

                    <div class="input-group input-group-seamless">
                       <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/backend_images/category_images/{{ $pro_data->product_image }}" class="img-thumbnail" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;" />
                    </div>

                  </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div> 
        </div>
           @endforeach
```

Hope this will work for.

Answer (score 0):

I would float the divs to the left with some padding and use clearfix if needed.

Answer (score 0):

All cards appeared in the horizontal manner because you might did't wrap them all without `.row` class

Because a set of css properties are applied to the `.row` class

Try the following approach:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be something like this. Added a `row` wrapper and `col` inside the loop. I assume `<div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">` is your container for all cards.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
    <!-- Input & Button Groups -->
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($category->products as $pro_data)
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card card-small mb-4">
                <div class="card-header border-bottom">
                    <h6 class="m-0">{{ $pro_data->product_name }}</h6>
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li class="list-group-item px-3">
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">

                            <div class="input-group input-group-seamless">
                                <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/backend_images/category_images/{{ $pro_data->product_image }}" class="img-thumbnail" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;" />
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
        <!-- / Input & Button Groups -->
    </div><!-- end of row -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in bootstrap 4 you can use columns in horizontal manner. You did't wrap them all without use .row class this is most important class.

this is the right way if you use bootstrap 4

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 mb-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 mb-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 mb-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 mb-4"></div>
</div>
@foreach($category->products as $pro_data)
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 mb-4">
        <div class="card card-small mb-4">
            <div class="card-header border-bottom">
                <h6 class="m-0">{{ $pro_data->product_name }}</h6>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item px-3">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">

                    <div class="input-group input-group-seamless">
                        <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/backend_images/category_images/{{ $pro_data->product_image }}" class="img-thumbnail" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;" />
                    </div>

                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```